# Angular Test does not call a promise callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

**Environment:**

- Angular 1.5.8
- Unit Tests with Karma/Jasmine

This is my controller, which aims to get a value from $stateParams and uses that, to perform a DELETE request, later on.
Right now  it should ask the user, wether to delete the object.
This is done with a sweetalert.

I have removed ngdoc comments and arbitrary SWAL config.

***ClientDeleteController.js:***

```
angular.module('app.data').controller('ClientDeleteController', [
  '$stateParams', '$q',
  function ($stateParams, $q) {
    'use strict';

    var vm = this;
    vm.clientId = $stateParams.id;
    vm.promptDeferred = null;

    vm.prompt = function () {

      // create promise
      var d = $q.defer();
      vm.promptDeferred = d;

      // create prompt
      swal({ .... }, vm.swalCallback);
    };

    vm.swalCallback = function (confirmed) {
      if (confirmed) {
        console.info('resolving...');
        vm.promptDeferred.resolve();
      } else {
        console.info('rejecting...');
        vm.promptDeferred.reject();
      }
    };

    vm.delete = function () {
      vm.prompt();
      vm.promptDeferred.promise.then(vm.performDelete);
    };

    vm.performDelete = function () {
      console.info('performing');
    };
  }]);
```

This is the test suite:

***ClientDeletecontrollerSpec.js***

```
describe('Controller:ClientDeleteController', function () {

  var controller
    , $httpBackend
    , $rootScope
    , $controller
    , scope
    , $q
    , $stateParams = {id: 1}
    , resolvePromise = true
    ;

  swal = function (options, callback) {
    console.info('i am swal, this is callback', callback+'', resolvePromise);
    callback(resolvePromise);
  };

  beforeEach(function () {
    module('app');
    module('app.data');
    module('ui.bootstrap');
    module(function ($provide) {
      $provide.service('$stateParams', function () {
        return $stateParams;
      });
    });

    inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$q_) {
      $controller = _$controller_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $q = _$q_;

      scope = $rootScope.$new();

      controller = $controller('ClientDeleteController', {$scope: scope, $q: $q});

    });
  });

  describe('basic controller features', function () {
    it('should be defined', function () {
      expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    });
    it('should get the client id from the state params', function () {
      expect(controller.clientId).toBeDefined();
      expect(controller.clientId).toEqual($stateParams.id);
    });
  });

  fdescribe('client delete process', function () {

    it('should ask the user if he really wants to delete the client', function () {
      spyOn(controller, 'prompt').and.callThrough();
      controller.delete();
      expect(controller.prompt).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should create a promise', function () {
      controller.prompt();
      expect(controller.promptDeferred).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should delete when the user clicked yes', function () {
      spyOn(controller, 'performDelete').and.callThrough();
      controller.delete();
      expect(controller.performDelete).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should not delete when the user clicked no', function () {
      spyOn(controller, 'performDelete').and.callThrough();
      resolvePromise = false;
      controller.delete();
      expect(controller.performDelete).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

});
```

The test `should delete when the user clicked yes` fails, the test `should not delete when the user clicked no`returns a false positive.

The `console.info(...)` within the swal mock logs the correct callback function. The logs in the function itself are also logged, which tells me, the callback is fired.
Since in the next line, I call either `vm.promptDeferred.resolve()` resp. `.reject()`, I expect the call to actually happen.

Nonetheless, the test result is `Expected spy performDelete to have been called.`.

I have mocked swal in another test the same way and it works fine.
I don't get why the promise won't be resolved.

Notice: When I don't store the promise directly on the controller but return it from `prompt()` and use the regular `.prompt().then(...)`, it won't work either.
The logs are the same and I like to split functions as much as possible, so it is easier to understand, easier to test and to document.

There are hundreds of other tests in this application but I can't see, why this one won't work as expected.

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: Another thing: In the actual app it runs as expected. Only the test fails, which makes it a test issue, obviously.

Comment: What happens if you do $rootScope.$digest() just after invoking delete in the test? In my experience something like that is necessary to make angular resolve promises during tests (either that or apply or flush on the http backend mock)

Comment: Thank you, this is it. If you'd like to post this as an answer, I'd like to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Cool :) no problem. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you do $rootScope.$digest() just after invoking delete in the test?

In my experience something like that is necessary to make angular resolve promises during tests (either that or $rootScope.$apply() or $httpBackend.flush())